# token_filter module: [node:nid] for custom block?

Tags: nodes, 8, tokens

Drupal: **8.1.7**

Module: [token_filter 8.x-1.0-beta1](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter/releases/8.x-1.0-beta1)

I have a custom block with a Text format that has *Global and entity tokens are replaced with their values* enabled.

The custom block has this value:

```
current-page:url:unaliased :          [current-page:url:unaliased]<br>
current-page:url:unaliased:absolute : [current-page:url:unaliased:absolute]<br>
current-page:url:unaliased:args :     [current-page:url:unaliased:args]<br>
current-page:url:unaliased:brief :    [current-page:url:unaliased:brief]<br>
current-page:url:unaliased:path :     [current-page:url:unaliased:path]<br>
current-page:url:unaliased:relative : [current-page:url:unaliased:relative]<br>
```

that will render as:

```
current-page:url:unaliased : http://www.example.com/node/1657
current-page:url:unaliased:absolute : http://www.example.com/node/1657
current-page:url:unaliased:args : , node, 1657
current-page:url:unaliased:brief : www.example.com/node/1657
current-page:url:unaliased:path : /node/1657
current-page:url:unaliased:relative : /node/1657
```

I am attempting to get the Content Id (e.g. **[node:nid]**) from the page, but that token is not available.

*Workaround using Inline Javascript:*

Node Id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- language: lang-js -->
document.write("[current-page:url:unaliased:relative]".match(/\/node\/(\d+)/)[1])
</script>
```

which will render as:

```
Node Id: 1657
```

I tried the following:

```
current-page:url:unaliased:args:node : [current-page:url:unaliased:args:node]
current-page:url:unaliased:args:0 : [current-page:url:unaliased:args:1]
current-page:url:unaliased:args:1 : [current-page:url:unaliased:args:1]
current-page:url:unaliased:value:node : [current-page:url:unaliased:value:0]
current-page:url:unaliased:value:0 : [current-page:url:unaliased:value:0]
current-page:url:unaliased:value:1 : [current-page:url:unaliased:value:1]
```

Without modifying the module how would I get **[node:nid]** from within a Custom block?

Answer (score 1):

[current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]

gives you the [node:nid] even when called from a block.

As per:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1265010

..."[current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:0] (The first value, of the array of arguments, of the unaliased URL of the current page)."